# Json-path json extractor that consist from nodes with fullstop in their names

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-extract

I use `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path` for quick accessing and modifying nodes.

Example of pattern is: `"$.dnode.meta"` helps to manage data on `meta` node level that located inside of `dnode`. Example of json is:

```
{
  "dnode": {
    "meta": "some value"
  }
}
```

I faced with json like:

```
{
  "dnode.meta": "some value"
}
```

And I need help to construct path where node name contains full stop.

I tried next examples but they do not work for me:

- `"$.[dnode.meta]"`
- `"$.\'dnode.meta\'"`
- `"$.\"dnode.meta\""`
- `"$.dnode\.meta"`
  ...

is any ideas how to construct path with json node that includes `.`?

Comment: "$['dnode.meta']"

Comment: It helps. Publish your answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with  `"$['dnode.meta']"`